# Meaning of ...interface{} (dot dot dot interface)

Tags: go

Below is a piece of Go code I have question about.
Specifically, what is `a` in this function?

```
func DPrintf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
  if Debug > 0 {
    n, err = fmt.Printf(format, a...)
  }
  return
}
```

Could anyone tell me what the three dots are here?
And what does `...interface{}` do?

Comment: The dotdotdot is called Ellipsis.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

A parameter type prefixed with three dots (...) is called a *variadic parameter*. That means you can pass any number or arguments into that parameter (just like with `fmt.Printf()`). The function will receive the list of arguments for the parameter as a slice of the type declared for the parameter (`[]interface{}` in your case). The [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) states:

> The final parameter in a function signature may have a type prefixed with .... A function with such a parameter is called variadic and may be invoked with zero or more arguments for that parameter.

A parameter:

```
a ...interface{}
```

Is, for the function equivalent to:

```
a []interface{}
```

The difference is how you pass the arguments to such a function. It is done either by giving each element of the slice separately, or as a single slice, in which case you will have to suffix the slice-value with the three dots. The following examples will result in the same call:

```
fmt.Println("First", "Second", "Third")
```

Will do the same as:

```
s := []interface{}{"First", "Second", "Third"}
fmt.Println(s...)
```

This is explained quite well in the [Go Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) as well:

> Given the function and calls
>
> ```
>    func Greeting(prefix string, who ...string)
>    Greeting("nobody")
>    Greeting("hello:", "Joe", "Anna", "Eileen")
> ```
>
> within `Greeting`, `who` will have the value `nil` in the first call, and `[]string{"Joe", "Anna", "Eileen"}` in the second.
>
> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.
>
> Given the slice `s` and call
>
> ```
>    s := []string{"James", "Jasmine"}
>    Greeting("goodbye:", s...)
> ```
>
> within `Greeting`, `who` will have the same value as `s` with the same underlying array.

Answer (score 11):

As far as the `interface{}` term, it is the empty interface. In other words, the interface implemented by all variables in Go.

This is sort of analogous to `java.lang.Object` or `System.Object` in C#, but is instead inclusive of every variable type in the language. So it lets you pass in anything to the method.