# Golang ...string type arg function

Tags: go

Why i cant put args in function

```
func ex(c string,ex ...string) { exec.Command(c,ex) }
```

get error `cannot use args (type []string) as type string`. Why?

Comment: This is an example of variadic arguments. You can read more about them in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of ...interface{} (dot dot dot interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669720/meaning-of-interface-dot-dot-dot-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `ex...` in the statement `exec.Command(c,ex...)` instead of just `ex`

Below as an example:

```
func ex(c string,ex ...string) { exec.Command(c,ex...) }
```